# HTML tags are not working when defined within stringbuilder

Tags: java, html, css, stringbuilder

I am defining HTML tags in String format, but I am not getting expected final result in HTML format.

```
StringBuilder loader = new StringBuilder(); 
loader.append("<div style=\"margin-left:20px\">").append("Loader id:").append(id).append("</div>").append("<br>");
```

Actual result that I'm getting is :

```
<div style=\"margin-left:20px\">Loader id: 12321</div><br>
```

But I want it be in HTML format.
I referred lot of similar questions, but I am unable to get expected result even after following those solutions.
Please help!!

Comment: What do you mean by "HTML format"? What string are you hoping to get?

Answer (score 0):

How are you determining your "actual result" ? Because the code you post works fine for me. For example:

```
jshell> StringBuilder loader = new StringBuilder();

jshell> loader.append("<div style=\"margin-left:20px\">").append("Loader id:").append("1").append("</div>").append("<br>");
$3 ==> <div style="margin-left:20px">Loader id:1</div><br>

jshell> System.out.println(loader.toString());
<div style="margin-left:20px">Loader id:1</div><br>
```